# what is exact relation among spring , java servlet and tomcat in mapping url to a resource?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am working on a dynamic web project in java with spring framework running on a tomcat.
in details which one is responsible for url mapping ? and what is role of each of them in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are very new to J2EE than I would like to suggest first go through JSP and Servlet then you will be able to understand how servlet mapping work, what  is web container and all.after getting idea about these thing it would be easy for you to deal with spring, as of now answer to your questions is seems to be broad category.